# Need Help Redirecting URLs With Parameters in Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect URLs like this one http://www.site.com.uy/filtro/?marca=42 to this http://www.site.com.uy/celulares?marca=42

I read lots of forums, docs, etc, for a solution and tried lots of rewrite rules, but I can't find a good solution. I think that the following code should work, but I have not luck.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/filtro/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^marca=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com.uy/celulares$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please, help me make this redirect work.
Thank you!!!

.htaccess file:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
     BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
     Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and let me know if it's working or not.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# /filtro/?marca=999 -> /celulares?marca=999
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*marca=(\d+).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^filtro/$ /celulares/?marca=%1 [R=301,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: @user2127832 Have you placed this htaccess file on the root of your site? Is this all you have in your htaccess file?

Comment: Hi again Shef, and thanks for your help.
The htaccess file is on the root of the site. Is not all I have in the file. I have anothers redirects that are working fine.

Comment: @user2127832 Maybe those other rules are interfering with this? Can you share all the rules you have in your file?

Comment: I made a backup of the htaccess file and delete all the other rules to test yours. The old rules where simple 1 line redirect from a static URL to another static URL, without parameters. I just delete them all to test and find a solution for this problem.

Comment: @user2127832 It's still not working with this single rule in there?

Comment: Chef, the site is a Magento site. I found anothers redirects that where in the original htaccess file and delete them all. Now your redirects works fine!!! Now I have to look rule by rule to find the one that is interfering, comment the rule and hope to not break the site. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This is the rule that is making the confilt:

## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

If I comment the rule, your redirects works perfect but I break all the site and every page gives a 404 error.

What can I do?

Comment: @Miguel I believe you can bypass it if you leave that rule as the last one. However, to be more specific you would have to share the rules of your htaccess so I can arrange them.

Comment: I have changed the order of the rules (yours first) and now everything is working!!! :D I will check as many pages of the site as I can to be sure that I every page is reachable. I will edit the original post to share the original htacess file. Thanks again for your help and for your quick answers! And sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Comment: @Miguel Great! Your English is fine. As long as we understand each other the fine details are not needed ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I had to remove the redirect. The redirect works fine, but it's breaking something in the check out process of the site. The site is an e-commerce site, so the check out page is the most important page of the site.